# Jobs randomly result in composer load class fail without even trying to process it

Tags: php, laravel

#### Context

- Laravel Version: 9.5.1
- Octane version: 1.2.4
- PHP Version: 8.1.3
- Database Driver & Version: PGSQL (12.9)
- Queue driver: Redis (with 8 workers on queue "low")
- Queue failed driver: Disabled (NULL)

#### Description:

Random instances of the same Job lead to composer autoload error. (Failed to open stream: No such file or directory).
I use pm2 to create the workers, the job doesn't even appear at the screen, just print directly in the storage/logs/laravel.log

Job code: https://prnt.sc/pCtZMRf8Er9f
(The backoff seems to work, despite of the job not being processed at the pm2 logs)

EmptyJob: https://prnt.sc/7z9myHScPrTh (For later testing purposes)

- First error: https://prnt.sc/om8PCthikwEs
- Second error (after some tries to fix it): https://prnt.sc/o7EIa2qW6wYO

Storage/logs: https://prnt.sc/P5CL-MkAl5jq

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Unfortunately I can't reference a repository.
The error seems too much random to replicate, sometimes I can run 20 jobs in a row flawless, I tried to test it on my local machine, but the WSL always give a curl timedout.
(In my local machine, the Empty Job failed once, despite not having any code at all)

(The error also happens when I dispatch multiple empty jobs)
https://prnt.sc/7z9myHScPrTh
After running 3000 EmptyJobs on 8 workers, I got 8140 lines of logs of:

```
include(/home/ubuntu/backend/vendor/composer/../facade/ignition/src/QueryRecorder/Query.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: There's a lot of context here, but unless it's buried in one of those links, I can't see a) the exact error message; or b) the line of code the error message refers to. I suspect the problem is that you're including a file with a relative path, which is problematic, because what it's relative _to_ is determined at run-time. If so, the solution is to _always_ use `__DIR__` (or `drname(__FILE__)`) to define include paths, because that's replaced with the path of the current file when it's _compiled_, so won't dynamically change.

Comment: @IMSoP I didn't require anything manually, always following the PSR import, https://prnt.sc/O9VWSY5kPVbS & https://prnt.sc/kTaVHshHf-9L shows every relative import, always using __DIR__, but this is builtin from Laravel.

Comment: Full exception log posted at https://pastebin.com/Df8Hj1NJ
There is no reference to my code btw, this is the exact problem I'm facing right now. Seems like a laravel core problem, but the issue on github was closed, I was told to search for help in stackoverflow, laravel.io, discord...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that this was a bad cache from opcache, rebooting the machine solved the issue, if you are facing the same issue, clearing the opcache may work.